# Check if a .json dictionary contains a user's id discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm Creating a bot with reCAPTCHA and leveling system.

The data is being stored in a .JSON file (temporarily, I'm trying to learn how to use MySQL and transfer the data to a proper db to prevent corruption of the data)

The .JSON file looks a bit like this

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "u": "224906648890638337",
      "m": 89,
      "lvl": 0,
      "score": 28,
      "captcha": false,
      "captchacode": 123456
    },
    {
      "u": "635042028643811357",
      "m": 0,
      "lvl": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "captcha": false,
      "captchacode": 12345
    ]
}
```

The Captcha code is the code that was sent to a user when they joined the server in the form of an Image.

What I want to do is have a verify command, that looks into the .JSON file and returns the captcacode of the user that sent the verify command.

And then it checks if the captchacode they were sent matches with the one they sent in the verify command.

My code for that:

```
@commands.command()
    async def verification(self, ctx, code):
        with open("JSON_files/testdb.json", "r") as f:
            db = json.load(f)

        if captchacode == code:
            await ctx.send("Captcha successfully completed ✅")
            remove_unverified = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="unverified")
            await ctx.author.remove_roles(remove_unverified)
        else:
            await ctx.send("⛔| Invalid captcha! Make sure to type: `!verification (code that was sent to you)` but without the brackets")
```

If anyone could help me with that, that would be great.
Comment or just ask if anything needs clarification.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are missing a `}` in your json file

```
      "captcha": false,
      "captchacode": 12345
      } <- here
    ]
}
```

In your verification function, you can iterate through every user and then check, if the captchacode matches.

Your verification function could be looking like this

```
@commands.command()
async def verification(self, ctx, code):
        with open("JSON_files/testdb.json", "r") as f:
            db = json.load(f)        
        
        
        captchacode_matched = False
        
        # iterate through every user
        for user in db["user"]:
            # get the captchacode
            user_captchacode = user["captchacode"]
            # check if the code matches
            if user_captchacode == code:
                captchacode_matched = True
                
                await ctx.send("Captcha successfully completed ✅")
                remove_unverified = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="unverified")
                await ctx.author.remove_roles(remove_unverified)
                
                # break the loop
                break

        # if no captchacode matched, send invalid captcha
        if captchacode_matched == False:
            await ctx.send("⛔| Invalid captcha! Make sure to type: `!verification (code that was sent to you)` but without the brackets")
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code should work, but I get an error when running it, which is the same error I'm getting with any other method:

`user_captchacode = user["captchacode"]`

Comment: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: wait nvm it was an error because i formatted the json file incorectly, thanks for the help!